# Saving changes of edited UIImage to same file

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimage

So this one should be simple for you.
I am having a trouble saving edited UIImage (just flipping it horizontally) to the same file. Instead, it creates a new one.

Code:

```
    // Get current photo
    id<MWPhoto> currentPhoto = [self photoAtIndex:_currentPageIndex];

    // Get current image object from photo
    UIImage *currentImage = [self imageForPhoto:(currentPhoto)];

    // Mirror it
    currentImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:currentImage.CGImage
                                                    scale:currentImage.scale
                                              orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];

    // Get NSData from image
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(currentImage, 1);

    // Create ALAsssetsLibrary to save data to photos
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:imageData metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"There was an error saving image");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Image should be saved");
            }
    }];
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Also tried with `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(currentImage, nil, nil, nil);`

but still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Assets Library framework is deprecated as of iOS 9.0, i suggest you tu use PHPhotoLibrary.
Anyway to write image to file you can use:

```
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

or

```
[imageData writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writeError];
```